# Merge two peoples edits to one master branch in github

Tags: git, github

Me and a coworker have been working off of one repository.

I made changes to it and saved it as branch B. He made changes and saved it as branch c.

When I do a pull request with the master and branch b. It basically makes the master into branch b. When I do another pull request with the master (now the same as branch b) with  branch c, the master branch becomes branch c.

Basically it seems like github just does full joins. I need to be able to do left joins so that I do not lose the edits people are making!

Comment: Are you merging your pull requests after you make them?

Comment: Yes, I make the pull request and then merge them. Is that not the correct method?

Comment: That is correct, you should be merging them. After you've merged B and C into master, master should contain the changes from both.

Comment: Do you understand how branches and merging works in git?

Comment: Perhaps I am not explaining this well. We are working on the same file!

Comment: Can you provide an example with a sample file, call it "testfile.java". 
 I want to see what the original file was, what your changes are, and what your coworker's changes are. During each merge please show what is happening to this file in the master branch.